# how to create release in repository using python code

Tags: git, tags, repository, release, gitpython

I created a tag in repository using git lib in python. 
this code works fine and creates a new tag:

```
repo = Repo(repo_path)
repo.create_tag('some tag..')
```

now I'm trying to make this tag into a Release and yet found a solution.

thanks

Comment: When you say “make into a release”, what do you mean?

Comment: Do you mean to create a `release` branch? Have a look [here](https://producingoss.com/en/release-branches.html) and [here](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) to understand the concept of release in software engineering.

Comment: I mean that when I create new tag in GitHub you have "Publish release" button at the end of the page, and then you can see this tag under Releases, I'm trying to find out if there's a flag in create_tag() that I could set..?

Answer (score 0):

You do not attach anything, the create_tag creates a tag that points to the current build in git hub, when you do repo.create_tag('some tag..') git creates a tag and links that snapshot of your project.

So all you need to do is create_tag and commit & push, thats it.